# Getting GitHub Repo Information

Tags: javascript, json, github

Is there a way to get simple repository information from GitHub (such as name, date uploaded, description, etc) with javascript and get it in a JSON file?

I am trying to get my repo information to import into my portfolio site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use github api, to get repository information, use [GET /repos/:owner/:repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get)

As for javascript, you can use https://github.com/octokit/rest.js

After correctly importing the library (on server side, install the package via npm and require that module, on client side, download the browser library and insert a script tag in your html file), then you can try something like this

```
// const Octokit = require('@octokit/rest') // server only 
const octokit = new Octokit();
const result = await octokit.repos.get({'owner', 'repo'});
```